# libsdl2-image-2.0-0 on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sdl-2

I am trying to install libsdl2-image-2.0-0 on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS and I am getting this error: "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libc6 (>= 2.14)"

I have "upgraded" to the latest version of Linux already and it wasn't my cup of tea. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS.

All of that said, how can I get SDL 2.0 to work on this version of Linux? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SDL2 is really new in the repository. Even in the newest release of Ubuntu, we got SDL2, SDL2-image but not SDL2-ttf.

So you got two choice :

1 - You need to compile the entire library yourself.

2 - Update your distribution, but your will still need to compile sdl2-ttf, because it's not in the official repository at the moment.